# Running from Idea cant find any resource unless explicitely setting resource dir

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, resources, java-module

Whenever I run from Idea, it cant find any resources.

Running from gradle `application` task is fine

Specs:

- JPMS project
- Gradle 5.6.1
- Openjdk 11
- Idea 2019.3

Investingating, no resources gets copied in the build directory (`$projectDir/classes/java/main/..`)

Some people solved by explicitely set the resource dir as:

```
sourceSets {
    main.output.resourcesDir = main.java.outputDir
}
```

This works for me too, but this doesn't feel solid and future proof

What is the right way to have Idea copying the resources into the output folder in JPMS projects?